# Does testing usage of ExecutorService add value?

Tags: java, unit-testing, executorservice

This is a class with the only purpose of calling a method from another class but with the addition of timing out after five minutes. With the other class already covered by unit tests, will creating a test for this method have any value other than increasing the test coverage percentage? It seems that the only thing to test would be verifying `ExecutorService` is functioning as expected though that seems unnecessary as it is a member of `java.util.concurrent`.

```
public class FileListRetriever {

    private final SshClientFactory sshClientFactory;

    public FileRetriever(SshClientFactory sshClientFactory) {
        this.sshClientFactory = sshClientFactory;
    }

    public String getRemoteFiles(String serverIp, Set<String> directories)
            throws ExecutionException, TimeoutException, InterruptedException {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        try (SshClient client = sshClientFactory.newClient(serverIp)) {

            Future<String> future = executor.submit(() -> client.retrieveFiles(directories));
            return future.get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        } finally {
            executor.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well in my opinion test for checking what happens after 5 minutes would add some value. I suggest using RxJava, it provides a great way to test things like that. You can inject your own scheduler, that is TestScheduler for tests and manipulate time yourself (so you don't have to wait 5 minutes, obviously). http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/TestScheduler.html